# show kendo grid columns on the footer

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, vertical-scrolling

I have a kendo grid where we show more results in the grid, so user has to scroll the browser window to see the data,here we didn't defined any static height on the grid.

When user scrolls the window, the user wont see grid header , here we want to give some info about which column he is looking at. we are thinking of creating a div with the grid columns and show this at the bottom of the window when user lost the visibility of header while scrolling. How to do this ? Is there anyother best approach ?

Comment: Why do not freeze column headers and have the user scroll only the content of the grid? Not sure which is the height of your grid but it is possible that the user is not at the top of the grid but also not at the bottom, so he/she will not see the column headers.

Comment: If scrollbar on the grid is enabled, there are 2 scrollbars on the page( window & grid scrollbar), want have only grid scrollbar. How to do this ?